# Print a Dynamic DIV with jQuery and google chrome browser issue

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, html, printing

i have one button in my page. when user click that button then i generate a div dynamically where i assign some text and image dynamically and print that div by jquery plug in.
i did this with a jquery div print plugin called **jquery.printElement.min.js**

my code works fine in IE and FF browser but behave wired in chrome. in case of chrome image is not assign or loading into div so only text gets printed.

here is my code by which i assign image and text into div and print that div by a jquery plug in.

```
$("#Print").click(function () {
    if (ImgPath != '') {
        sHtml = "<div id='dvPrint' ><table>";
        sHtml += "<tr><td>" + "<img src='" + ImgPath + "' height='600' width='400' border='0'/>" + "</td></tr>";
        sHtml += "<tr><td>" + $('#lblTxt').html() + "</td></tr>";
        sHtml += "</table></div>";
        var $dvPrint = $(sHtml);
        //alert(ImgPath);
        $dvPrint.printElement();  // jquery div print plug-in
    }
    else {
        alert("Image not found for print");
    }
    return false;
});
```

the plug-in url :- https://github.com/erikzaadi/jQueryPlugins/tree/master/jQuery.printElement

Comment: my guess is that it is just a loading problem. that the images are not loaded at the time chrome tries to print and that FF and IE probably wait until the images are loaded.  **EDIT**: Probably it will work if you preload the images before you call `$dvPrint.printElement();`

Comment: Why, when assigning the src, you used `'` and then `"`? `<img src='" + ImgPath + "'`. This can cause such a problem

Comment: @Tiago Salzmann `'` is used at the beginning and the end of the `src` the `"` is of the string so it correct.

Comment: Oh, i thought ImgPath had it already...

Comment: thanks the moment i remove all single quote then it works for chrome.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bMzUt/27/

Comment: Its not working here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not really sure, why Chrome is behaving that way, but I am guessing it has to do with that plugin

You can try doing this manually. Make a very simple page, which will take a url parameter, which will be the imagePath

e.g "/printImage.php?src=path/img.jpg"

```
...

<body onload="window.print()">

<?php
   echo '<img src="' . $_GET["src"] . '"/>'
?>

...
```

Open a popup with the url to that page and have it call window.print() on load

Comment: here i ask about jquery and u gave me the sample of php.

Comment: Granted, I did not provide jQuery code, my answer is still very much in context. I provided an alternative to using that particular jQuery plugin. The php code is just for reference as to what the page should look like.